# Space.SE moderator resignation

Tags: discussion, moderator

Due to a highly turbulent situation, the moderator status network wide is very chaotic.

Main meta post:

[Firing mods and forced relicensing: is Stack Exchange still interested in cooperating with the community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper)

For this site, it means I'm suspending activity, while called2voyage, moderator on both here and Astronomy, has stated they will keep up moderation as for now.

**Update:** I'm resigning.

Comment: We support you in what you think is best.

Comment: what a mess! full support!

Comment: Thanks for all you do and have done. Follow your conscience.

Comment: Thanks for your hard work. I can't imagine what a lot of the mods are going through right now.

Comment: Sad to see you go, but totally understand your decision. Do you think you'll stick around as a user?

Comment: I didn't notice your update until it was [pointed out](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1411/12102) and I'm really sorry to find out about it. Thank you for your thoughtful and steady moderation, and I really hope you continue to participate!

Answer (score 6):

It is possible for users to also participate in communication.

We can read and vote accordingly on the comments and answers to the heavily downvoted [An Update to our Community and an Apology](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334248/303080).

---

**update:** @Machavity's [comment](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/space-se-moderator-status/1391?noredirect=1#comment5189_1391) is high importance so I'll echo it in this post:

> [Apology 2.0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334551/an-apology-to-our-community-and-next-steps) seems to have finally learned the lessons V1 did not

but let's wait to see how this new wording is bourne out in corrective actions...

Comment: so it seems to be a case of they've said the right words, now will they do the right things?

Comment: @JCRM They have honored their word so far, though Monica says she is still not satisfied after they contacted her but we don't have more details on that yet.

Comment: Things don't seem to be going so well @called2voyage. Hopefully just a false start :(

Comment: @JCRM Yeah, I saw that. :(

Comment: Backup link: [An Update to our community and an Apology](https://web.archive.org/web/20191223172246/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334248/an-update-to-our-community-and-an-apology).