# January 2020 Moderator Election — Community Interest Check

Tags: discussion, moderator, election

This community last had moderators appointed in 2017, so it's been a while...  In addition to that, you may have noticed that [one of the current mods — Hohmannfan — has stepped down from their moderator position](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1390/8813).

Since moderators were last appointed in this community, we've started and "graduated" and experiment: and pro-tem moderators [are now elected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332180/208518), just like "regular" moderators. As such, to find a replacement for Hohmannfan, we're looking at scheduling an election to start somewhere in January 2020. To avoid finding ourselves in a situation where an election would fail due to an insufficient number of candidates, though, I'm posting this to try to assess the community members' willingness to step up and nominate themselves, when the actual election's nomination period starts.

Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position, should we decide to run an election. Like I mentioned, we're looking at scheduling the nomination period to start some time in January '20.

**NOTE:** This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up, so you don't have to put up your whole election nomination. [Here](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1426/8813) is the actual election announcement.

Comment: I'm surprised there haven't been more answers so far...

Comment: @Mast With [the ongoing Monica debacle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/244695), [Stack Exchange basically admitting they're about to be sued over it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338271/244695), and [the frustratingly vague pronoun mess](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336366/244695) it shouldn't be that surprising.

Comment: @Machavity While that will (and should) deter some people from running, that won't be a problem for everyone, right?

Comment: @Mast Only 1/3 of all the moderators have quit, so the answer is no

Answer (score 24):

**Edit 2020-01-14:** Due to yesterdays [firing of two highly competent and popular community managers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342039/172266), I am no longer willing to take on any additional moderator roles within the Stack Exchange network.

<s>I would run if and only if nobody better placed does (and of course only if the community would welcome me).</s>

My activity on Space Exploration has been moderate, but I am an active moderator over at Earth Science Stack Exchange, which has some overlap with Space Exploration (my day-to-day-work is with weather satellites, which involve both Space Exploration and Earth Science).

Comment: No offense intended, but I was kind of thinking 'nobody' might be a better candidate for the position.

Comment: @JamesJenkins moderation is a lot of work and having three moderators, especially distributed over different time zones makes their job easier.

Comment: @JamesJenkins No offence taken.  Do you mean because of the context in which Hohmannfan steps down means nobody *should* join, or do you mean I am personally unsuitable?  My view is that moderators who have stepped down in protest have done so individually.  If there had been a collective decision to a strike, I would not put myself forward, even if I disagreed with the strike decision.  But there has not been such a debate prior to the individual resignations.

Comment: My comment is not personal. My [update meta post here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334744/217279) explains my reasoning. While the claim was ["remove links to a legal fund campaign from user profiles, posts, and comments'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338270/217279) they seem to have only removed the ads.  Many links to gofundme remain some fairly blantiient.

Comment: @JamesJenkins Some people [have reported links being deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339238/172266).

Comment: @gerrit They are being deleted, seems to be most heave on SE.Meta, and those who are most vocal there.  You can probably keep yours, as long as don't stir the pot too vigorously.

Comment: @gerrit very sorry to hear this, (and that, and everything), but it is completely understandable

Comment: It's just [been announced](https://space.stackexchange.com/election), is there any possibility that you'd reconsider? I certainly appreciate your reasons for changing your mind, but the community is still here, active and enthusiastic, and would still certainly benefit.

Comment: @uhoh You are asking a a difficult question.  Why not you?

Comment: @uhoh Ping me again in five days, please?

Comment: @gerrit I know, sorry! Moderation is hard! I thoroughly enjoy all aspects of participation, but moderation requires additional skills. Since the internet is "written in ink" I don't want to enumerate all of the many ways that I'd fall short. ;-)

Comment: Turns out voting for you was better then voting for nobody.  Congratulations.

Answer (score 1):

While my activity here is modest, if it becomes a situation of "We need a moderator or we will be shut down for lack of people to handle flags, etc" ping me. I will run in the interim if needed to keep the site going.

I am a moderator on three other sites (fitness, martial arts and med sci), so I am familiar with the moderation process.

Comment: We're not at risk of having the site shut down, but the reason we prefer to have three mods is so that if one mod needs to take a break it doesn't leave a lone mod handling all the work.