# Announcing a Pro Tempore Moderator election

Tags: discussion, election

> **Note:** The election date was pushed back a month, due to some ongoing back-end work on the election mechanics, in order to automate some steps.

**Summary**: Space Exploration Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://space.stackexchange.com/election/1) on **February 17, 2020** to bring in one more moderator.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Starting on February 17, 2020, users can [nominate themselves](https://space.stackexchange.com/election/1). Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On February 24, 2020, if there are two or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll simply appoint the candidate. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on March 3, 2020.

(Note for current moderators: there's no need to nominate yourself even though you'll likely get an email saying you should. The system assumes the first election is a graduation election, which would mean moderators would need to be re-elected. This isn't that sort of election.)

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Comment: You might want to add a link to this announcement in the [community interest check question](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1411/33).

Comment: Done, @gerrit :)

Comment: What happens if there is no eligible candidate?

Comment: The nomination period is extended for one week. If, after that period, there still aren't enough candidates, then the election is cancelled, and we work with the remaining moderation team to set a new date, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I'm bumping this to remind everyone that self-nomination is now less than two weeks away, as long as this doesn't get rescheduled again. If anyone is interested in joining the mod team, make sure to stop in on or after February 17 and before February 24 to post your nomination. The link to the election location where nominations will be made is in JNat's post above--please take note this is using the standard election tools, not meta.